# MySQL query to join 2 tables based on votes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I've a web application where I use 2 tables, one for storing product information and other for storing votes of each product.

Now I'd like to display the products based on the number of votes the products had got. Below is table structure

Products:

```
PRODUCT_ID  TITLE
1           product1
2           product2
3           product3
4           product4
```

Votes:

```
PRODUCT_ID  USER_ID
1           1
1           1
2           2
3           2
```

And I am expecting a result to display the products in descending order of the votes

```
PRODUCT_ID  TITLE           VOTES
1           product1        2
2           product2        1
3           product3        1
```

Currently I am using a query like this

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, count(*) AS total FROM products p 
INNER JOIN votes v ON v.product_id = p.product_id  GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 110
```

Products table has around 30,000 records and votes tables has around 90,000 records.

Now the problem is it takes a lot of time(randomly between 18 to 30 seconds). Since the number of records in the tables aren't that high, I wonder why it takes such a huge amount of time.

One thing noticed is when I run the query for the second time it fetches the results in few milli seconds which I think is the ideal time for a not so complex query like this.

Again I am pretty new to database side of programming.

I am not sure if there's anything wrong in the query or is it the table structure which isn't efficient (at least to fetch the records quickly).

Comment: query does not look ok, u need to select from votes instead of product since you are doing the count and secondly u need to use EXPLAIN select ... (your query to see what is says)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'd change the query to select from votes

Comment: Apologies you do not need to change it but you can select from products !! It should work. I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query is fine, although I would be inclined to format it differently:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, count(*) AS total
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     votes v
     ON v.product_id = p.product_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 110;
```

As mentioned in another answer, an index on `votes(product_id)` would definitely help the query, if you don't have one already.  Even with the improvement in the `join` performance, you still have the overhead of an aggregation.  And, in MySQL that can be a lot of overhead.

If you are expecting lots and lots more votes -- getting into the millions -- then you may have to take another approach.  One approach is to add a trigger to some table (perhaps the `products` table that keeps track of votes as they come in.  *Then* the query would fly.  Another approach would be to periodically summarize the data, similar to using a trigger but using a job instead.